# No response from jQuery .post even though PHP is returning correct data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my `jQuery`:

```
function SelectSubCats(cat_num) {
    console.log("Select SubCats..");
    $.post("ajax.php", {
        _populateSubCats : 1,
        cat_num : cat_num
    },
    function(data){
        console.log("Data: " + data );
    });
}
```

**I am not reaching the `console.log` statement is the problem.**

in `ajax.php`:

```
else if(array_key_exists('_populateSubCats', $_POST)) { // {{{
    $cat_num = $DB->escape($_POST['cat_num']);
    print GetSubCats($cat_num);
} // }}}

function GetSubCats($cat_num) {
    global $DB;
    $returnHTML = '';

    $query = "SELECT sc_i_num, sc_s_subcategory FROM subcat "
            . "WHERE sc_i_c_num = {$cat_num} "
            . "ORDER BY sc_s_subcategory";  
    $result = $DB->query($query);
    $returnHTML .= "<option value=''></option>";
    while($obj = $DB->next($result)) {
        $returnHTML .= "<option value='{$obj->sc_i_num}'>{$obj->sc_s_subcategory}</option>";
    } 
    return $returnHTML;     
}
```

The return generates `<option>`s for a `<select>`.  The idea is, there are categories and subcategories.  The jQuery function above is called in the `onchange` of the category `<select>`.  Eventually I'd like to replace that `console.log` with an append to add the new data to the sub-category select.  But right now, I am just trying to get a response.  I have logged the php side and am getting the exact response I need.  What else is going on?

Comment: What are you seeing as being returned in the network tab?

Comment: first open your browser's developer tools, go the xhrs and trace the ajax request and make sure it gets the response, then if you had response in the console, copy the response with all the headers and stuff, and paste it here for us to figure out the problem.

Comment: I am also getting `junk after document element` from console in firefox.

Comment: @Samsquanch in the Network tab I am getting 200 and the `response` is the html returned from the php, as expected.

Comment: you missing `success` in line ` function(data){`

Comment: @DrixsonOseña - function data works as success

Comment: @DrixsonOseña: [It’s not an object, it’s just an argument list.](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: Any other errors in the console?

Comment: @KickingLettuce, what happens if you just do `console.log(data);`?

Comment: Try specifying what type of return you're getting? put `, 'html'` after the last function.

Comment: @Samsquanch  nothing at all... no log.

Comment: @Kerry How would you do this? where?

Comment: @KickingLettuce, where the `});` is in your code, change it to `}, 'html');`.

Comment: @Kerry I got a response now by adding it!  Yup, got it working.  Go ahead and mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the type of response you want by adding `, 'html'`.

i.e.:

```
function SelectSubCats(cat_num) {
    console.log("Select SubCats..");
    $.post("ajax.php", {
        _populateSubCats : 1,
        cat_num : cat_num
    },
    function(data){
        console.log("Data: " + data );
    }, 'html' );
}
```